# How do I know the language, and the request software (browser) in Express?

Tags: javascript, api, express

When they make a request to my creator server in Express, and I try to know the language, and the browser software, with `req.language` and `req.software`` it gives me undefined

My current code is:

```js
app.get('/api/whoami',  (req, res, next)=> {

    let json = {"ipaddress": req.ip, "language": req.language, "software":  req.software}

    res.json(json)

    next()
})
```

to see the complete code in more detail visit https://replit.com/@Michael-Liendo/boilerplate-project-headerparser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
req.headers["user-agent"]        // browser info
req.headers["accept-language"]   // user's browser language
```